# How do I pass a variable from view to controller in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

This is my index.html.haml:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'user'
.title
  %h1 Port Testing
  = form_tag('port_testing/test', method: 'get') do
    = text_field_tag :hostname, 'localhost', size: 50
    = check_box_tag('Port 80', '80')
    = label_tag('80')
    = check_box_tag('Port 443', '443')
    = label_tag('443')
    = check_box_tag('Port 28009', '28009')
    = label_tag('28009')
    = check_box_tag('Port 2195', '2195')
    = label_tag('2195')
    %button(type="submit") Test
```

In my routes.rb, I have this:

```
  match 'port_testing/test', :controller => :port_testing, :action=> :test
```

This is my port_testing_controller.rb:

```
class PortTestingController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end
  def test
      puts "\n"
      puts @params["hostname"]
  end
end
```

Right now when I click the "Test" button, I get this:

> Started GET "/port_testing/test?utf8=%E2%9C%93&hostname=localhost" for 127.0.0.1
>   at 2012-03-07 13:51:33 -0500
>    Processing by PortTestingController#test as HTML
>    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"G£ô", "hostname"=>"localhost"}
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms
>
> NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
>   You might have expected an instance of Array.
>   The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]):
>    app/controllers/port_testing_controller.rb:7:in `test'
>
> Rendered vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/actionpack-3.1.2/lib/action_dispatch/middl
>   eware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (6.0ms)
>   Rendered vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/actionpack-3.1.2/lib/action_dispatch/middl
>   eware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (3.0ms)
>   Rendered vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/actionpack-3.1.2/lib/action_dispatch/middl
>   eware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (155.0ms)

How do I pass to the controller which checkboxes are checked along with what is entered in the text field?

Comment: @fl00r Can you be more specific?

Comment: `puts @params["hostname"]` convert to `puts params["hostname"]`

Comment: @fl00r Thanks! That worked. How would I store my check_box statuses in the params variable so I can get the statuses in my controller then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `params` variable in Rails isn't an instance variable, so your controller method should say:

```
def test
  puts "\n"
  puts params["hostname"]
end
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. How would I store my check_box statuses in the params variable so I can get the statuses in my controller then?

Comment: `params` is a hash of everything that the form sends to the controller.  Try just doing `puts params` in the controller to see what the check boxes are being stored as.

Comment: When I do `puts params`, only the checked checkbxes are in the hash. I can make a workaround but it would have been nice to have all the checkboxes in the `params` hash instead of just the checked ones.

Comment: I don't think has to do with `Rails` to be honest.  I don't think browsers submit check boxes that aren't checked.

Answer (score 0):

I know I did it.. you can puts all the params, by looping through them.. do this.. I'd bet your value is in there already.